# Add a string to an x-axis of integers

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting a graph on a x axis (solution concentration) against efficiency (y). I have this set up to display for x between 0 to 100, but I want to add another datapoint as a control, without any solution at all. I'm having issues as this doesn't really fit anywhere on the concentration axis, but Id like to add it either before 0 or after 100, potentially with a break in the axis to separate them. So my x-axis would look like ['control', 0, 20, 40,  60, 80, 100]

MWE:

```
x_array = ['control', 0, 20, 40, 50, 100]
y_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
plt.plot(x_array, y_array)
```

Trying this, I get an error of:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'control'

Any ideas how i could make something like this work? Ive looked at xticks but that would plot the x axis as strings, therefore losing the continuity of the axis, which would mess up the plot as the datapoints are not spaced equidistant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a single point to your graph as a separate call to `plot`, then adjust the x-axis labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_array = [0, 20, 40, 50, 100]
y_array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x_con = -20
y_con = 1
x_ticks = [-20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
x_labels = ['control', 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x_array, y_array)
ax.plot(x_con, y_con, 'ro')  # add a single red dot

# set tick positions, adjust label text
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(x_ticks)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(x_labels)
ax.set_xlim(x_con-10, max(x_array)+3)
ax.set_ylim(0,7)
plt.show()
```

[image]